# Writing with RTL language inside of formulas in LYX

Tags: lyx, hebrew, right-to-left

I recently started using LYX and it's GREAT!
I have configured it for using Hebrew and everything works fine except I can't write in Hebrew inside formulas normally. In the equations it won't let me change language in lyx (even when I use \text) and if I do the forbidden act of changing the language in Windows it write from LTR instead of RTL. I wanted to know if there is a simple way to deal with this problem?
Thanks in advance for any help available!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: What exactly should the result be? Suppose I have this in English: http://i.stack.imgur.com/pfvqF.png. What should happen in Hebrew? Are the symbols different? Do they get reversed? I'm not sure how you could mix LTR with RTL on one line, so I'm wondering if there are RTL systems of mathematical notation? Or...?

Comment: In Hebrew we write the math from left to right and the Hebrew from left to right. If I were to write the word "where" from your example in Hebrew ( "כאשר"), because Hebrew is written from left to right, it would write "רשאכ" the equivalent of "erehw" in English. Again that only happens when I change the language through Windows (which makes all sorts of problems and I've been told not to do). If I change the language through LYX it just throws me out of the formula.

Comment: Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. [For one thing, some of us cannot just make up some Hebrew to experiment with. For another, it may matter how exactly you are typesetting the language.] I'm not sure, but I don't think that LaTeX can switch directions mid-paragraph. But I'm not at all certain of this.

Answer (score 1):

When setting up [typesetting Hebrew using XeTeX](http://www.guyrutenberg.com/2015/03/21/creating-an-hebrew-document-in-lyx-2-1-with-xetex/) in Lyx, it is possible to write Hebrew inside formulas. The Hebrew will look reversed in LyX but will look fine in the output.

Comment: Is there a bug report with a minimal example for the incorrect LyX display? If not can you make one at http://www.lyx.org/trac ? We would like to correct the problem but without an example it is difficult.

Comment: I've updated http://www.lyx.org/trac/ticket/7207 with a minimal working example.